# Android getDrawable performance

Tags: android, drawable

I have a question (hope it is not stupid). Is getDrawable(int resId) slow ?
And is it faster than decoding resource with BitmapFactory ? And is it faster to call getDrawable(resid).getInstrinsicHeight() than decoding with Bitmap.Options with inJustDecodeBounds = true and than get the width ? I know that decoding of bitmaps is slow, and they consume a lot of memory, but what about getDrawable(int redId) and the result Drawable object ? It is allocate a lot of memory. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is Similar to this one :

[Efficient way of creating Bitmap out of Drawable from res (BitmapFactory vs Type Casting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840967/efficient-way-of-creating-bitmap-out-of-drawable-from-res-bitmapfactory-vs-type)

"You can take a look at the source code for Bitmap factory at http://source.android.com specifically the code for decodeResource.

I would reason that using BitmapFactory is preferred but in either case if you are decoding multiple bitmaps then you should call getResources() once and store the result for use as the resources argument for the functions."

Further, i would recommend you to go through 1st 2 articles here, to learn about the workaround for using either of these effficiently :

http://www.coderzheaven.com/tag/getdrawable/

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. But I still don't understand why is preferable to use decodeResource. I have the source code, but actually I don't know which operation is fast and so on. I see that there is synchronization in getDrawable, but is that the reason ? And why you should call getResources once ? As I see getResources is called only if mResource variable is null nad resources will be created only on the first call eventually. Please fix me if I am wrong.
Thanks in advance.